# Magic square of square

Tags: pythagorean-triples, magic-square

I am trying to solve magic square of square
First let me explain my approach when will be the magic square form if we have
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline A² &B²&C² \\ \hline D²&E²&F²\\ \hline G²&H²&I²\\ \hline \end{array}$$
Then we have equations like-
$$A²+B²+C²=x...(1)$$
$$D²+E²+F²=x...(2)$$
$$G²+H²+I²=x...(3)$$
$$A²+E²+I²=x...(4)$$
$$G²+E²+C²=x...(5)$$
$$A²+D²+G²=x...(6)$$
$$B²+E²+H²=x...(7)$$
$$C²+F²+I²=x...(8)$$
By solving all equation I found that-

1. $B²+H²=A²+I²=C²+G²=D²+F²=2E²$
   2.$H²+I²=C²+E²=A²+D²$
   3.$B²+C²=E²+I²=D²+G²$
   4.$G²+H²=A²+E²=C²+F²$
   5.$A²+B²=E²+G²=F²+I²$

From above equation we can find the value of $A²,C²,G²,I²$. Which are-
$$2A²=H²+F²$$
$$2C²=D²+H²$$
$$2G²=B²+F²$$
$$2I²=B²+D²$$

So magic square can be made as
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline (F²+H²)/2&B²&(D²+H²)/2\\ \hline D²&(D²+F²)/2 = (B²+H²)/2 &F²\\ \hline (F²+B²)/2&H²&(B²+D²)/2\\ \hline \end{array}$$

They are like Pythagorean triplets where $A,C,G,I,E$ are  hypotenuse. So can  pythagorean triplets like $((a,b,c) => (a²+b²=c²))$ :-
$$(F,H,A), (B,D,I), (D,H,C), (B,F,G), (B,H,E), (D,F,E)$$  is exist- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Example - if i have triplets like $(63,16,65)$ and $(33,56,65)$ then there should be other triplets like $(63,33,C_1),\ (16,33,C_2),\ (63,56,C_3) ,\ (16,56,C_4)$

Comment: After I sent the data sample in email, I lost you email address. Can you snd me another email?

Comment: So what you want to find is a “Parker Square”?

Comment: I'm working on this problem as well; trying to go farther by exploiting the inherent multiple Pell-equation structure. If you like you can download a current draft : http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/Helms_2022_magicSquareOfSquares2_draft.pdf . Perhaps there is something in this for you...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some "candidates" where $C \le 100,001.\quad$ They do not appear to  be "complete" but there are no others  under $100,000$ where $C$ is odd.

$$
(957,3724,3845) \quad (957,124,965) \quad (3843,124,3845) \\
\\
(2375,4200,4825 ) \quad (3367,4200,5383 ) \quad (3367,3456,4825 ) \\
 (4697,1104,4825 ) \\
\\ 
(707,5076,5125) \quad (2813,4284,5125) \quad (3325,3900,5125) \\ (4675,4284,6341) \quad (4675,2100,5125) \\
\\ 
(4123,8364,9325 ) \quad (4123,4836,6355 ) \quad (6875,6300,9325 ) \\
 (7973,4836,9325 ) \\
\\
(215,23112,23113) \quad (215,912,937) \quad (23095,912,23113) \\
\\ 
(13725,23452,27173) \quad (22755,23452,32677) \quad (22755,14852,27173) \\
\\ 
(8613,33516,34605) \quad (8613,1116,8685) \quad (34587,1116,34605) \\
\\ 
(6141,35380,35909) \quad (6141,23140,23941) \quad (27459,23140,35909) \\
\\ 
(32881,22920,40081) \quad (39919,22920,46031) \quad (39919,3600,40081) \\
\\ 
(27615,29072,40097) \quad (36735,29072,46847) \quad (36735,16072,40097) \\
\\ 
(21375,37800,43425) \quad (30303,37800,48447) \quad (30303,31104,43425) \\
 (42273,9936,43425) \\
\\ 
(6363,45684,46125) \quad (25317,38556,46125) \quad (29925,35100,46125) \\
 (42075,38556,57069) \quad (42075,18900,46125) \\
\\ 
(7015,46248,46777) \quad (7015,4752,8473) \quad (46535,4752,46777) \\
\\ 
(9951,51040,52001) \quad (40449,32680,52001) \quad (5871,47560,47921) \\
 (32079,35600,47921) \\
\\ 
(38675,45732,59893) \quad (38675,27132,47243) \quad (53395,27132,59893) \\
\\ 
(5325,62900,63125) \quad (29325,55900,63125) \quad (29325,22724,37099) \\
 (45453,43804,63125) \quad (58893,22724,63125) \quad (61875,12500,63125) \\
\\
(16779,62620,64829) \quad (16779,46060,49021) \quad (45621,46060,64829) \\
\\ 
(2737,76416,76465)\quad (2737,9384,9775) \quad (30257,70224,76465)\\
 (72593,24024,76465) \quad (75887,9384,76465) \\
\\ 
(37107,75276,83925) \quad (37107,43524,57195) \quad (61875,56700,83925) \\
 (71757,43524,83925) \\
\\ 
(23925,93100,96125) \quad (23925,3100,24125) \quad (29877,91364,96125) \\
 (82677,49036,96125) \quad (96075,3100,96125) \quad 
$$

Comment: are you also checked for even number

Comment: @B. Patel
  I am working on even numbers. Send me an email (see my profile) and I will send you a complete list onece I find it. In the mean time, has any of this been usefu?  :)

Comment: No they didn't work. When i tried to find for even numbers i found that  E must have 4 triplets and two of the triplets should have hypotenuse as sides because if magic square has triplets like$ (B,H,E),(D,F,E),(A,I,E),(G,C,E)$ (since also$ E²= (A²+I²)/2 $and $E² =(G²+C²)/2$) and, since A,I, and G,C are already a hypotenuse as you can see on the question. So I am trying to make triplets with only hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending you a program that generates candidate triples over a possible C-domain of $500$ at a time. It generates triples for a given C-value and also triples that can be formed from different elements of column a or b such as

$$
(31,480,481) \\
(480, 360, 600)\quad   b+++\\
(360, 480, 600)\quad   b+++\\
(319, 360, 481) \\
***\\
(720, 638, 962 )\\
(720, 960, 1200)\quad   a+++\\
(960, 720, 1200) \quad  a+++\\
(960, 62, 962) 
$$